# Designing a toxic ore?

Tags: chemistry, materials

I would like to design a natural ore that is very toxic to humans. This ore needs to be natural. And weapons made from this material cause necrosis.

Comment: So, you want to create something new that already exists? I don't really understand what exactly you are asking here?

Comment: @Secespitus i would like some help designing my ore,Is it wrong? i guess...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Title says,I guess,I wont write my important story details ya know...I fear copycat like anyone.

Comment: Have you considered radioactivity? This seems like an obvious path. So, any uranium rich deposit (ore?) would be a place to start

Comment: Smaller than a village,bigger than a planet,If this question gets on hold or closed,then i have nothing to do here..set me free ;)

Comment: i just reported my own question,hope ya all are happy :D.

Comment: There are two difficulties with your question. Firstly, the point "about designing a natural ore that is toxic to humans." Are you looking an existing toxic ore or are you trying to invent one? Secondly, the ore can be made into weapons causing necrosis. Now necrosis is a specific condition, so its toxicity has to be necrotic and this too narrow. Either you need a toxic ore to make poisonous weapons or a toxin that can be used on weapons and will cause necrosis. Perhaps if you edit your question to better reflect what you want. Hope this helps.

Comment: A moment of silence for @Myrmidon

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about necrosis, but Cinnabar is a great toxic ore, historically. It creates pure mercury if it's introduced to heat, and leads to death rather quickly. Also, for style, it forms *bright red crystals* around *volcanic areas* and the common name is *dragon's blood*. It's just awesome

Comment: Wow. [Cinnabar](http://geology.com/minerals/cinnabar.shtml) actually exists. I just HAD to look that one up.

Comment: 'Mercury poisoning is a type of metal poisoning due to mercury exposure.[3] Symptoms depend upon the type, dose, method, and duration of exposure.[3][4] They may include muscle weakness, poor coordination, numbness in the hands and feet, skin rashes, anxiety, memory problems, trouble speaking, trouble hearing, or trouble seeing.[1] ' [mercury poisonong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_poisoning)